# How to pass C++ function as callback to Python?

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, callback, python-c-api

I am using the Python 3 C API to interface with some Python code.

I have instantiated a Python object from C++ using `PyObject_Call` and I have been able to modify some of its attributes using `PyObject_SetAttrString`. One the attributes I would like to modify is a callback function, how can I instantiate a Python object from one of my C++ functions?

Comment: You cannot send a C++ function to Python code. You need to create a callable Python object which calls that function. (if I understood correctly what you are asking :/ )

Comment: That's literally just what I asked for. How do I create this callable Python object which calls my C++ function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to create a Python object which is callable, and when it is called, it ends up calling a function implemented in C (or C++).

I would implement a new class, as specified in Python [Type Objects docs](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html). It may implement any kind of constructor etc. you may need, but most importantly for this purpose, it should implement the [`tp_call`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_call), which will make instances of this class callable (as if there was a [`__call__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__) method implemented in Python).

The implementation of `tp_call` is in C/C++ and you can create instances of this class, which are Python objects and can be passed to any Python code.

See also: [Defining Extension Types: Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/newtypes_tutorial.html)